# XLib - Window hints behave differently when I construct XWindowAttributes in the main function?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I am experimenting with some fundamental Xlib stuff.  I am creating a basic window and creating an OpenGL context for it.

I am trying to prevent the user from being able to resize or manually full screen the window.  I added the code:

```
XSizeHints hints;
hints.min_width = hints.max_width = setup.w;
hints.min_height = hints.max_height = setup.h;
XSetWMNormalHints(dpy, win, &hints);
```

This worked at first.  However after experimenting with it I have found that it mysteriously stops working sometimes.  It is not a matter of unusual window managers or anything like that, I am using the default windows manager installed with Ubuntu.  What causes it to change, strangly enough, is whether or not I include this line in main:

```
XWindowAttributes atts;
```

It does not matter where I put it.  At the beginning, or inside a loop, or even after the return.  As long as I put that somewhere in main the hints prevent resizing (just to be clear, any name for the variable works).  It does not matter if I use it at all or not, it was initially there for a call to XGetWindowAttributes.  I discovered the problem when I tried moving that into a separate function call.  If I take it out, the window will have a full screen button and I will be able to shrink it.  I have experimented with declaring the variable other places, such as in the struct where I contain the Window and GLXContext.

What is going on here?  The way I see it I either have a very subtle and unusual bug coming from my virtual machine or something weird like that, or I have missed some obvious piece of information.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You didn't set the `flags`, eg. `hints.flags=hints.flags = PMinSize | PMaxSize`. The flags will contain a random stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no explanation for why declaring a XWindowAttributes instance in main was making it work, but I did figure out what was wrong with my code and I was able to make it behave as expected when I made the following changes:

1. Do not create XSizeHints directly as shown above.  Create it as follows:

   ```
   XSizeHints *hints = XAllocSizeHints();
   ```
2. Set flags in the object specifying which variables are used:

   ```
   hints->flags = PMinSize|PMaxSize;
   ```
3. Use XSetWMNormalHints and XSetWMSizeHints:

   ```
   XSetWMNormalHints(dpy, win, hints);
   XSetWMSizeHints(dpy, win, hints, PMinSize|PMaxSize);
   ```

I also put a pointer to the hints in my struct containing data about the window.  All together the code above became:

```
XSizeHints *hints = wind->hints = XAllocSizeHints();
hints->flags = PMinSize|PMaxSize;
hints->min_width = hints->max_width = setup.w;
hints->min_height = hints->max_height = setup.h;
XSetWMNormalHints(dpy, win, hints);
XSetWMSizeHints(dpy, win, hints, PMinSize|PMaxSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that came here:

**1. Communicating with the Windows Manager**

It's all about convention like said at 12.3 in the "Xlib Programming Manual VOL1". Some WM will completely ignore hints like max & min size, because eg they manage Windows as Tiled Windows. So, how YOUR Window Manager will get your choices is an issue.

**2. Make things in the right order.**

This will perhaps answer your question : ***"What is  going on here?"***

Most difficulties with X comes from the order you make things. I encountered the same trouble as yours, and solve it because I saw I didn't follow the right process. 
Chapter 12.3.1 from the "Xlib Prog Manual" says:
'Once the client has created the windows, **BUT BEFORE IT MAPS THEM**, it must place properties to help WM manage them effectively'

In your case, it means you cannot use XSetWM* functions AFTER your window is mapped. Some properties will have an effect, some others not, and sometimes some will be overridden with bad values.

**3. The right order. (AFAIK)**

a. Set an Error Handler

b. Get a Display

c. Init your Context (here GLX) & get a Visual from it.

d. set Window Attributes (events mask, ...)

e. Create your Window

e. Set WM Properties (eg your sizehints, min/max size, class, title, ...)

e.1 always init pointers you need with XAlloc* when possible

e.2 use X11r4 **XSetWMProperties** that will put them all at once, avoid use of deprecated functions.

e.3 XFree your 'pointers'

f. Set the Wm Protocols you are interested in (WM_DELETE_WINDOW, ...)

g. set some others properties according to your needs (eg _NET_WM_PID, ...)

h. Finally, Map your Window

**4. See what happens : use xprop**

xprop will report how your window is known by your Windows Manager. 
If your size hints were properly set, you will see some lines like:

```
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: 550, 200
                user specified size: 500 by 500
                program specified minimum size: 500 by 500
                program specified maximum size: 65535 by 65535
```

Hope it helps future users,

(PS: the previous answer TS@Oct 27 '14 at 15:26 has an error: XSetWMSizeHints expect an Atom as 3rd arg.).